# I need help using the "equals" command

Tags: c++

I've started studying C++ language yesterday, and to try to understand it a little better, I've been testing some commands that I've learned and searching some new ones around the web.

I've been struggling to use the ".equals" command, since a error occurs all the time. I've found some similar things on the web, but nothing helped me so far.

A simple code I've made to test it out:

```
{
int a;

scanf("%i", &a);
if(a.equals(1)){
    printf("10/10");
}
```

Basically, it's meant to show "10/10" if I type in "1" in the prompt, but this simples code results in the "request for member 'equals' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'int'" error.

Like I've said before, I found some other similar problems around, but they always had something to do with another command on the code, while mine is basically only the "equals" command...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Classes and `equals` in C? Are you sure? Is this Objective C or C++ or C# maybe?

Comment: It is c++.
I'm using the DevC++ software, maybe this might be relevant

Comment: I get `prog.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token` with your code.

Comment: there is no such thing in c++ either.  `if (a ==1)` is a c/c++ way.

Comment: C++ is another language than C. You should change this in your text and change the tag, too.

Comment: OK, with C++ I get this error instead: `prog.cpp:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token`

Comment: On a sidenote: Why C++? Most people learn C# or Java these days instead of C++. I used C++ for many years and am happy I don't have to anymore and can use C# instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive types in C and C++ don't have methods defined on them.  If you want to compare two integer values just use the `==` operator:

```
if (a == 1) {
    printf("10/10");
}
```

If on the other hand you want to compare two strings, you need to use `strcmp`:

```
char s[] = "hello";
if (strcmp(s, "hello") == 0) {
    printf("equal\n");
} else {
    printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Comment: Right. Is there a way to compare it with strings? For example, if I want it to print "10/10" if a = test, what should I do?

Comment: @LuizFernando Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: C++ strings (as in `std::string`) can be compared with `==`.